# Select all rows from table but keeping conditions intact

Tags: java, hibernate, jpql

Hi this code only gives me 1 row back because of the GroupBy:

```
@Override
    public Map<Integer, List<Cluster>> getPartnerIdClusterMap(boolean minorOnly, boolean foreignCountriesOnly) {
        BooleanBuilder predicate = new BooleanBuilder();
        if (minorOnly) {
            predicate.and(qCluster.type.eq(ClusterType.MINOR));
        }
        if (foreignCountriesOnly) {
            predicate.and(qPartner.country.code2.ne("nl"));
        }

        return from(qCluster)
                .innerJoin(qCluster.partner, qPartner)
                .where(predicate)
                .where(qPartner.country.code2.ne("nl"))
                .map(qPartner.id, GroupBy.list(qCluster));

    }
```

**This is what I gladly want to know:**

I want to select all the rows of the Cluster table. But I want to keep those conditions (innerJoin, where clause etc.) intact.

So I had tried this:

```
    return (Map<Integer, List<Cluster>>) from(qCluster)
            .innerJoin(qCluster.partner, qPartner)
            .where(predicate)
            .where(qPartner.country.code2.ne("nl"));
```

To be honest Netbeans casted for me the above code from JPQLQuery to a Map type. But unfortunately the code doesn't work. Because I get the following error:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: com.mysema.query.jpa.impl.JPAQuery cannot be cast to java.util.Map
```

And here is a screenshot of the error:

[image: screenshot]

Can someone maybe help me, please?

Comment: If you remove the map it probably won't return a map. assign it to an Object type and then debug what is the actual type, then change the method signature to that.

Comment: Ah ok I had casted it now to a Object type link: http://pastebin.com/rJpJuwys

But then I get the syntax error in Netbeans: Object cannot be converted to  Map

Comment: You'd normally have to convert the query results to a map manually. Btw, I'm no criteria expert but you don't seem to actually execute the query.

Comment: Ah yes I forgot to mention I execute the following line of code from the EnrollController.java:

model.addAttribute("partnerIdClusters", partnerService.getPartnerIdClusterMap(true, true));

Comment: @superkytoz can you paste the pastebin.com/rJpJuwys to imgur and share? I can't open that from workplace. Or even better give the exception message

Comment: That's because you are still returning it, and the method signature is still a Map as return type. do something like Object o = from... ; return null; , then put a breakpoint and debug the actual runtime type of o.

Comment: @Karthik screenshot of the pastebin.com/rJpJuwys link: http://i.imgur.com/9dw7L0R.png 

Ah Netbeans calls it a compilation error so here is a screenshot of the exception message: http://i.imgur.com/BOkU33h.png

Comment: Can you post the relationship between the Partner and Cluster? Is it bidirectional? `List<Partner>` or `List<Cluster>` or both exists as bidirectional?

Comment: In the class Cluster I can see the following:

@ManyToOne
 private Partner partner;

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you if you make the both Partner and the Cluster has one-to-many or many-to-many relationship:

```
return from(qCluster)
            .innerJoin(qCluster.partner, qPartner)
            .where(predicate)
            .where(qPartner.country.code2.ne("nl"))
            .map(qPartner.id, qPartner.clusters);
```

I believe that you have a `List<Cluster>` in `Partner` (property name is clusters as above). Else, your requirement wouldn't be valid.